# stringify some obj and crash the browser

Tags: javascript, json, browser, openlayers

I tried to stringify event from map([openLayers](https://openlayers.org/)), and the following error appeared:

`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. So I used this [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value) and I tried again, returning this warning: `[Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.`.
After all,the page crashed.

I've tried on Google Chrome, Firefox and Brave browsers.
Google Chrome and Brave showed the same warning. Firefox doesn`t showed any warning.

```js
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
    const seen = new WeakSet();
    return (key, value) => {
        if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
            if (seen.has(value)) {
                return;
            }
            seen.add(value);
        }
        return value;
    };
};

const map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() })],
    view: new ol.View({ center: [0, 0], projection: 'EPSG:4326' })
});

map.on('click', (e) => {
    const event = JSON.stringify(e, getCircularReplacer());
    console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: Check out some of the third party libraries that claim to do that e.g. https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted

Comment: It has been same, page crashed.

Comment: OpenLayers provides some functionality to stringify most data worth sharing at strings, like Features. What exactly do you want to do with the event? Maybe stringifying parts of the event (e.g. Coordinates) and possible selected Features could be sufficient?

Comment: @Rob I did that but I wanna know reason crashed.